# Generate upper-case in a udev rule?

Tags: scripting, udev, text-formatting

I have a  use case with cross-platform context which makes me want to generate symlinks under a `/dev/disk/by-X` directory that have an uppercase version of data returned by `blkid`.

Is there a built-in way to achieve this or can I use a pipe in the `IMPORT{program}` syntax (i.e. `IMPORT{program}="blkid | toupper"` or will I need to write and invoke a wrapper script that takes care of this?